# Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1" with app created through ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm starting with ember. I followed the Getting Started guide at [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com) and managed to create a new ember application by running the following commands:

```
npm install -g ember-cli
ember new sample-app
```

Everything went successful and I can see the app files generated by ember-cli. Soon after that I did:

```
ember server
```

The command line shows:

```
version: 1.13.13
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Build successful - 4426ms.

Slowest Trees                                 | Total               
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
ConcatWithMaps: Concat: Vendor                | 3498ms              

Slowest Trees (cumulative)                    | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
ConcatWithMaps: Concat: Vendor (1)            | 3498ms
```

The problem comes when I go to http://localhost:4200. Nothing gets loaded and the Chrome console is showing the following:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `sample-app/app`
```

I tried to fix this by reinstalling ember-cli, bower and npm but nothing is working.

Here's additional info in case is necessary:

```
$ ember -v
version: 1.13.13
node: 5.4.0
npm: 2.14.10
os: darwin x64

$ npm -v
3.5.3

$ bower -v
1.7.2
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there's a discrepancy between the 'npm' version being reported by ember and npm itself - so make sure you have a clean 'PATH' set up when building via ember and running npm manually - as this will be sure to give you headaches.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

This is a bug due to a new version of jQuery which ember is not yet able to handle. For now you can change the following line in your `bower.json` file. Then run `bower install` and it should work.

```
"jquery": "^1.11.3",
```

to

```
"jquery": "1.11.3",
```

A new version of ember.js is [imminent](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/12793) which should fix [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5316).

Comment: `"^1.11.3"` now resolves to new jQuery version 1.12 (try `bower info jquery` or visit the [jQuery blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/))

That means that [this assertion in Ember](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.7/packages/ember-views/lib/system/jquery.js#L17) fails.

This caused, among other symptoms, our continuous integration builds based on `ember test` to _hang_ (with no error reported).

Comment: it is important to restart the server too, at least I needed to.

Comment: In addition to restarting the server you will need to run `bower update` to get the correct version of jquery.