# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `ui/app` loader.js:164

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I build and serve my ember application using the following commands:

`ember build`
`ember serve`

Both of which work as expected.

Then I goto the the following localhost:4200 URL to view the application and see the following error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1  ember.debug.js:5921
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `ui/app` loader.js:164
```

Not really sure why it cant find jquery or the ember module ?

ember version:

```
version: 2.2.0-beta.3
node: 0.12.6
npm: 2.14.10
```

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.2.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.8",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "^3.5.0",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0",
    "slick.js": "~1.4.0",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "~3.1.12",
    "videojs-youtube": "~1.2.8",
    "tooltipster": "~3.3.0",
    "OwlCarousel2": "~2.0.0-beta.3",
    "ember-mousetrap": "~0.2.0",
    "rsvp": "~3.0.18",
    "bootswatch": "v3.3.4+1",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.7.3",
    "progressbar.js": "~0.8.1",
    "selectivity": "~1.1.0",
    "select2": "~4.0.0",
    "select2-bootstrap3-css": "~1.4.6",
    "jquery-mentions": "~1.0.1",
    "jquery-autocomplete": "~1.1.1",
    "jssocials": "~0.2.0",
    "ember-pusher": "0.1.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.5",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "^3.5.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember": "2.2.0",
    "select2": "~4.0.0",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0",
    "qunit-notifications": "~0.1.0"
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for ui goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ember server",
    "build": "ember build",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.0.2",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^0.2.3",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^0.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "^2.2.0-beta.2",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.0.0",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-cookie": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "0.5.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-redis": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "0.2.0",
    "ember-cli-divshot": "^0.1.7",
    "ember-cli-dotenv": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.9",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-cli-less": "^1.1.1",
    "ember-cli-notifications": "2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-pusher": "0.1.2",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "0.3.15",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth": "^0.7.3",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-oauth2": "^0.7.2",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-torii": "^0.8.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-tooltipster": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-data": "1.13.5",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-mousetrap": "0.2.0",
    "ember-rapid-forms": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "0.2.0",
    "ember-truth-helpers": "1.2.0",
    "ember-validations": "2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "torii": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using stable version of ember `version: 2.2.0` (without beta part)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1" with app created through ember-cli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that its due to a bug of ember with the new version of jquery.

I simply downgraded the jquery version in my bower file.

Take a look at this issue resolved by Lawree:

[Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1" with app created through ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1)