# Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-load-initializers`

Tags: ember.js, ember-rails

i am getting error after running compiled ember rails application. Here is the error while inspecting the page.

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-load-initializers` imported from `(require)`
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `active-model-adapter` imported from `account-settings/initializers/active-model-adapter`
```

here is my `bower.json` and `package.json` files:

```
    {
      "name": "account-settings",
      "dependencies": {
        "ember": "^2.0",
        "ember-cli-shims": "0.0.6",
        "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
        "ember-data": "^2.0",
        "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
        "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
        "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
        "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
        "jquery": "^1.11.3",
        "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
        "qunit": "~1.20.0"
      }
    }

package file: 

{
  "name": "account-settings",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for account-settings goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "active-model-adapter": "2.0.3",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "ember-cli": "1.13.13",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-coffeescript": "1.13.2",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-emblem": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-cli-rails-addon": "0.0.13",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7",
    "emberx-select": "2.0.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

Can you please suggest the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Could not find module \`ember\` imported from \`ui/app\` loader.js:164](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703545/uncaught-error-could-not-find-module-ember-imported-from-ui-app-loader-js1)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue suddenly after a deploy, without changing any critical code. The two current answers do not address this issue for me. This seems to be its own isolated problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a related to issue [#5316](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5316) in `ember-cli@1.13.13`.

As mentioned in the issue thread, you could either try updating `ember-cli` to `1.13.14` or pinning `jQuery` to `1.11.3` in your `bower.json` to solve it.

Comment: I am deploying it via capistrano. If I change it in json files and deploy , will it work ?

Comment: The answer is speculative. Not sure what your exact problem is. Also, I am not familiar with Capistrano to comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that its due to a bug of ember with the new version of jquery.I simply downgraded the jquery version in my bower file.

Take a look at two following link:

1- [Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember` imported from `ui/app` loader.js:164](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703545/uncaught-error-could-not-find-module-ember-imported-from-ui-app-loader-js1)

2- [Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1" with app created through ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1)