# Ember load-initializers error: Could not find module `ember-load-initializers`

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-cli

I'm having trouble updating an older Ember app.

I've ported the code into a new, empty ember app and installed the dependencies.  I get no error when I serve the app, but when I inspect the browser console, I see that the app failed to launch.

`` Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember/load-initializers` imported from `<my-app>/app` ``

I've seen a similar SO post that suggested this was caused by issues with ember-cli and jquery. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599351/uncaught-error-could-not-find-module-ember-load-initializers)

However, that post is over a year old and I'm running an up-to-date version of ember along with an newer jquery library.  Sure, it's no guarantee, but it seems a bit unlikely that this is still an issue for ember-cli.

My app/app.coffee file is pretty basic (no additions)

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

`import Resolver from 'ember/resolver'`

`import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'`

`import config from './config/environment'`

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true

App = Ember.Application.extend
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix
  Resolver: Resolver


loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix)

`export default App`
```

From the console, I can verify that my app is using the expected jquery version:

`$ Ember.$.fn.jquery
"3.2.0"`

However, from the command line, I get a different version.

`$ bower jquery -v
1.8.0`

I'm not sure whether that's meaningful or a red herring.

At any rate, my ember-cli is fairly recent.

`ember-cli: 2.12.0`

I've added links to the [package.json](https://gist.github.com/bnd5k/cef97c8e9a603cf29f6503df0642d81a) and [bower.json](https://gist.github.com/bnd5k/1b742709fd1e04216f76097d3c6eaeed) files, in case they contain any clues.

At this point, I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot the issue.  The depency

Comment: try updating  "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3" and  remove node_modules and tmp folder and try npm install

Comment: It was worth a shot, but it didn't change the current behavior.

Comment: Can you try to import `ember-load-initializers`. Such as `import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'`

Comment: @BenDowney I tried like you did `import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'` I got the same error but then when I change it to `import loadInitializers from 'load-initializers'` this fixed the error.

Comment: This is an old problem but have you tried ember-load-initializers? They changed the naming in February this year https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/b85fbea229097e353ee244e8aea24893cb7b3646

Answer (score 3):

```
import Resolver from './resolver'

import loadInitializers from 'load-initializers'
```

Update those line app.js file and try it

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done this already, in the `app.js`, switch

```
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers'
```

over to

```
import loadInitializers from 'ember-load-initializers'
```

they changed the naming conventions of [loadInitializers recently](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/commit/b85fbea229097e353ee244e8aea24893cb7b3646).