# Restart ember-cli too often than usual

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have to restart ember-cli too often, every couple of files I edited, it would report some sort of error related to a file under the `tmp` folder. I am sure there is nothing wrong because everything is ok after a restart.

```
ember serve
```

I didn't install "watchman" so I just used nodewatch. Is it because of this?

Anyways, any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
ember -v
version 2.2.0-beta.3
node 4.2.3
npm 2.14.10
Ember 2.2.0
Ember data 2.3.1
jQuery 2.1.4
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (among others) after updating to the same versions of Ember/EmberCLI yesterday.  I found this:
[Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1" with app created through ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1/34702715#34702715)
 that suggested it was related to the version of JQuery.  I changed my bower.json:

"jquery": "1.11.3"

and ran bower install.  No more problems.

I hope this helps

Comment: Heres the link to where I found that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702284/getting-uncaught-error-assertion-failed-ember-views-require-jquery-between-1/34702715#34702715