# Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am new to ember and using the following,

```
Ember: v1.13.3
jquery: v1.12.3
```

But I am getting the following error
`Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember Views require jQuery between 1.7 and 2.1`

I have referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/34702715/4350834 and doesn't fix my error.

But in my `bower.json` file I have the following

```
{
  "name": "jquery",
  "main": "dist/jquery.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "package.json"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "jquery",
    "javascript",
    "browser",
    "library"
  ]
}
```

How can I overcome the error with the ember.js version(v1.13.3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just updating the jQuery version to v2.1.0, fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

add `resolutions` option in `bower.json`

```
 "resolutions": {
    "ember": "1.13.3",
    "jquery": "2.1.0"
  }
```

---

*Edit Updated*

You could use JQuery `2.1`. Try by updating jQuery to v2.1.0.